# How to test browser automation code with rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm working on a project that requires a lot of browser automation to retrieve data, populate forms, etc. I've used capybara and selenium in the past to do automated testing of websites, but I've never used capybara and selenium as the application (that now needs tested).

Google is next to worthless as every search on "how to test browser automation code" returns results on how to use browser automation to test your code (which, I get it, is what most people use browser automation for).

Has anyone done anything like this? Any tips? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Whether one should even be testing tests is one that is likely to be hotly debated. However, at a meta level, you just approach it like you do any other form of testing.

If you're trying to test a web-scraping application or some kind of web-based "data fetcher" (regardless of whether it's based on an API or you're filling/scraping pages), then it's just another application that needs the same sort of unit and systems tests that any other application would need.

1. Decide what each test should allow it to pass or fail given:

   - No value.
   - Some known input that should pass the test.
   - Some known input that should fail the test.
2. Add some fuzzing or boundary conditions to make sure your tests pass or fail correctly with invalid or unexpected inputs.

There's not much else to say, really. If you scrape a given page, your application should populate certain variables; does it do so, and are those values correct? Does it "populate the forms" correctly, whatever that actually means? If it's a PDF, does the generated PDF match the expected PDF or at least relevant sections of it?

Testing is testing is testing. If your code is a scraper or data aggregator that doesn't make it fundamentally different from any other kind of application. You still want to test your unit or system results for known-good, known-bad, and undefined results or behaviors.